# TinyMCE 4.x resize event

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I've been searching around (both on SO and around the web) to try to figure out how I can get the current height of the ***editor*** after the user has resized it.  The TinyMCE 4.x docs don't show any kind of resizing event.  When searching around I did come across the `ResizeEditor` event but that seems to apply only when objects *within* the editor are resized (which makes it seem like a poorly named event).  Despite that, I tried to listen to the ResizeEditor event just to see and it does appear to fire whenever I resize the editor (though, I'm unsure if that's because the actual editor is resizing or because elements within the editor are getting resized, too.  In any case, only the event object is passed in as an argument to the listener and I don't see any way to get the editor's current height (after the resize) from that event.

So, is there a way I can do this?  To listen to the ***editor*** being resized and get its height?

thnx,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the entire height of the editor (Menus, Toolbars, StatusBar, content area, etc) with code like this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer().clientHeight
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer().clientWidth
```

When you call `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()` you are getting the outermost `div` that contains all that makes up TinyMCE.  From there it is just standard JavaScript to get the relevant dimensions of that element.

Here is an example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/qigaab/18

Comment: Well the problem is that the .getContainer() call is returning null regardless of how I call it:  This is what I ran in the console: 

`11:50:17.520 tinymce.activeEditor.getContainer()
11:50:17.524 null
11:50:43.619 tinymce.get('scratchpad-component').getContainer()
11:50:43.623 null`

I tried getting the editor and combing through the properties of that object and nothing is popping out at me as a value for the current height of the editor.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows exactly how you have TinyMCE setup along with your code that returns `null`?  Without seeing running code it is hard to know precisely why you get `null`.  You should certainly check your entire chained JavaScript first (`tinymce` ...  `tinymce.activeEditor` ... etc) to ensure you are indeed locating the editor.

Comment: I created a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that shows using JavaScript to get the width and height.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working (I don't use jsfiddle all that much) but this is the gist of what I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/1rn4u8tL/1/

When the ResizeEditor event is fired I don't see where I can get the current height.  Further, after that event is fired the first time, every time the mouse moves over the editor, that event fires again.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's different from what I had before and what you have in your fiddle but that is working for me.  Perhaps it was all the banging my head against the desk that I've been doing all morning.  Thank you very much for your help!